# How to prove if two functions are equal up to order $n$ at $a$, and this limit equals to $0$?

Tags: calculus

Is the statement true that: Two functions $f$ and $g$ are equal up to order $n$ at $a$ if and only if:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0?$$

How to prove from "equal up to order" to the equation?

Does "Two functions $f$ and $g$ are equal up to order $n$ at $a$" literally mean:
$f(a)=g(a), f^\prime(a)=g^\prime(a),...f^{(n)}(a)=g^{(n)}(a)$ ?

Comment: The definition I've seen of "equal up to order $n$ at $a$" is literally that $\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0$.  If in addition, you assume $f$ and $g$ are $n$-times differentiable at $a$, you can prove this is equivalent to $f^{(k)}(a) = g^{(k)}(a)$ for all $k\in\{0,\dots, n\}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo That looks like an answer. Please consider posting it as one.